# I want to write a program that reads a string & then print that capitalize every alternative letter in the string. Eg school becomes ScHoOl

Tags: index-error

Code Not working

I had tried all my efforts to make it run

```
str1 = input("Enter a string: ")
lenght = len(str1)
print("Orignal string = ",str1,"\nOrignal string lenght = ",lenght)
str2 = " "

for i in range(0,lenght+1):
    if i%2==0:
        str2+=str1[i].upper()
    else:
        str2+=str1[i]

print(str2)
```

> IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow.  I do think this question can be addressed and answered in it's current form; but, you do need a tag for the language you're using to be added. Also, It is a common\basic programming issue; so, that indicates you have to not done research on the problem and the exception;  I would also say that your title should reflect the unexpected issue you're observing, not your intention with your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
`str1=input("Enter a string: ")
lenght=len(str1)
print("Orignal string = ",str1,"\nOrignal string lenght = ",lenght)
str2=" "
for i in range(0,lenght):  #no requirement of lenght+1
         if i%2==0:
                  str2+=str1[i].upper()
         else:
                  str2+=str1[i]
print(str2)`
```